# How to fix fridge door foam

Tags: refrigerator

The fridge door wobbles as you can see from the picture: the foam on the fridge door has some problem. When the door is opened, the hinge in the fixture moves in the hollow part of the foam.

[image: Top view of the fridge door]

Is there way I can find the part for the door foam, or is there a way to fill in thick foam in the fridge door?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt the foam was doing anything.  The problem is the plastic that was helping retain the hinge pin is broken off.

I'd get a metal angle bracket and use an angle grinder to match the profile of the hinge pin and then mount it to the side of the door (hopefully that looks like metal).  You might need to mount it to the back face of the door given the hinge is likely pushing in that direction when the door is opened.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The foam is very dense and thick. The hinge pin has a plastic sleeve, and sleeve was originally fixed in the foam. I wondered if there is way to pour in some foam and fix the hinge sleeve.

Comment: There are different densities of foam.  1/2 pound or 2 pound foam are two different spray foam.  I don't know what they use in a fridge door.  You could go buy some XPS - extruded poly styrene and cut a chunk of it to fit.  The box stores sell it in 2x8 sheets for $10, this foam is used under foot and while compressible it is quick dense.

Comment: I did not use the angle bracket as I am confident to cut or grind it. Instead I used a piece of wood and fix the problem. Thanks.